# conda does not install packages in environment

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I installed anaconda on my windows and created a new environment `abc`. I activated `abc` environment using `conda activate abc` and then used the command `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch` to install pytorch. But when I use `conda list` command after deactivating my environment, I can find all the pytorch packages there. Does this mean that the packages were installed in the `base` environemnt instead of `abc`? Why are same packages listed when I call `conda list` from the environment or from outside?

Why is `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs` empty? Isn't it supposed to contain `abc` environment?
Also I cannot find torch packages in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs` but they are present in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

> But when I use conda list command after deactivating my environment, I can find all the pytorch packages there. Does this mean that the packages were installed in the base environemnt instead of abc?

No, when you deactivating your env (e.g. abc) you go to base env.
then `conda list` will show the pacakges in base env

> Why is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs empty? Isn't it supposed to contain abc environment?

It's strange. you can use `conda create -n test python=3 -y`, then check whether the `test` env is in there.

> Also I cannot find torch packages in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs but they are present in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages. Why is that?

becuase you install a python packages, it should be there (site-packages).
but you should install packages within env, so try to solve the env problems first.

and, if you still have some install problems, beside read the doc, conda is easy to reinstall, just delete the mini/anaconda folder and reinstall using .exe/.msi etc again.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs empty?

The default location for environments on windows is not in the `ProgramData` folder, but under `Users` somewhere (cannot check right now), because the ProgramData folder needs admin privileges to write to by default. You can check easily by runnning this command:

```
conda info --envs
```

which prints a list of environments and their location

> Also I cannot find torch packages in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs

That is not the location where python packages are installed to. It is only a sort of cache that anaconda uses for downloads. `site-packages` is where python packages are located

> but they are present in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages. Why is that?

That, plus your description from above has me believe that you have probably installed `torch` also in the `base` environment. Check if you find `torch` in the `site-packages` for the `abc` environment.

To find out where that is, use the `conda info --envs` command from above

Alternatively, you can always run this command in your anaconda prompt to find out where torch is imported from:

`python -c "import torch; print(torch)"`

Try it from your base and also from your `abc` environment

Comment: You are right, the path to env is user\.conda\envs\nlp .But I still cannot understand why all my packages are being installed in base environment (I tried installing other packages) ? I always activate my environment using `conda activate abc` then install using `conda install` command.

Comment: Also whenever I try to install anything like this I get an error "Error message : EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment. environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3" and then I restart terminal by running it as admin and follow the same steps again to install any package.

Comment: Are you in anaconda command prompt or in normal `cmd`? Have you tried anaconda prompt in case you ahve so far only used cmd?

Comment: You can also try `conda install -n abc` to install to the `abc` env specifically

Comment: I am using Windows Powershell in new windows terminal. Ok, I found all packages I wanted to install in user\.conda\envs\pkgs folder (not present in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs). Does this mean they have been installed correctly in abc environment and not in base environment. But still when ever I use `conda list` command after deactivating my environment it list all the packages I installed in my environment (running `conda list` in the abc environment also lists the same packages).

Comment: As I said in my answer `pkgs` is not the installation target directory. But if they are listed when doing `conda list` in your environment and you can find the python packages also in `user\.conda\envs\abc\site-packages`, then they are installed correctly to that env. Also check the first line of the `conda list` output. It will tell you for which env the listed packages are. My guess is that you have probably installed similar packages to your base env